# SQLite Error code number 1: Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord

So I have a discord.js bot and I'm using SQLite3 to store some mute information.

```js
const sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var modDb = new sqlite.Database('moderation');

modDb.serialize(function() {
    modDb.run("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mute");
    modDb.run("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ban");
    modDb.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mute (id INT, username TEXT, discriminator TEXT, dateBegin INTEGER, dateEnd INTEGER, modID TEXT)");
    modDb.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ban (id INT, username TEXT, discriminator TEXT, dateBegin INTEGER, dateEnd INTEGER, modID TEXT)");
});
```

Then I have code continuing on another file

```js
const sqlite = require("sqlite3").verbose();
var db = new sqlite.Database('moderation');

db.serialize(function() {
  var stmt = db.prepare(`INSERT into mute values(
                        ${user.id},
                        ${user.username},
                        ${user.discriminator},
                        ${Date.now()},
                        ${Date.now() + muteTime},
                        ${message.author.tag});`,
    function(err) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
    });
  stmt.finalize();
  console.log(stmt);
  console.log(Date.now());
  console.log(muteTime);
  db.each("SELECT * FROM mute", function(err, row) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(row);
    }
  });

});
db.close();
```

When I run this it gives me this error in the console:

```
{ Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "#3522": syntax error errno: 1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR' }
```

The `#3522` is referring to the message.author.tag in which it returns the author's name and discriminator from the discord api. I'm thinking it is a syntax error but I don't know where the syntax error is. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the values into `db.prepare` correctly:

```
var stmt = db.prepare(`INSERT into mute values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`);
stmt.run(user.id, user.username, ...)
```